# How to structure vue app when using global components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently, we try to figure out, how we can structure our vue code for this use case:

- routing will be handled by the backend, so basically we don't creating an SPA here
- we want to use vue to replace some jquery plugins. So on some sites of our website we have e.g. a drop-down component or a date picker component ...
- one site will be small SPA
- on each site, we have a navigation, where we also want using vue

How should this be structured? Is it one big vue application?

My idea is to build two vue applications:

- one for the small SPA
- one for all the components we need on different sites

Anybody can help out here?

Answer (score 0):

For developing SPA in vuejs. Please refer to these two links

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli
and
https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-2.0-simple-routing-example

And for integerating VueJS in existing web page
you can follow the official website of vuejS